# Button remains tappable after removing from view hierarchy - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I'm trying to show and hide a view based on a certain state. But even after that view is removed from the hierarchy, it still remains tappable for a few moments, leading to phantom button presses. This is occurring only in iOS 16 to my knowledge.

Note that this only occurs when using the `.zIndex` modifier, which I need in order to transition the view out smoothly. The bug occurs with or without a `transition` modifier, however.

Minimum working example (tap the show button, then tap the hide button multiple times. If it worked correctly, the hide button handler should only trigger once, since it is removed from the hierarchy. In reality it can be triggered many times)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                print("show")
                show = true
            } label: {
                Text("show")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(8))
            }
            
            if show {
                Button {
                    // this can be triggered multiple times if you tap fast
                    print("hide")
                    show = false
                } label: {
                    Text("hide")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(64)
                        .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(8))
                }
                .zIndex(1) // if we remove the zindex, it won't happen. but then we lose the ability to transition this view out.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experience this bug? I don't know a workaround besides removing `zIndex`, is there a way to fix it without losing transitions?

I filed a feedback for this FB11753719

Comment: even without the .zIndex() is still executing more than once, for me

Comment: what ios version? @JavierHeisecke

Comment: my version is iOS 16.0